# Use Hardhat ES5 together with Sveltekit ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, sveltekit, hardhat

I'd like to use Sveltekit together with hardhat but hardhat uses commonjs `require` syntax, if run `npx hardhat test` with `js` ending I get the error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module hardhat.config.js from node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\config\config-loading.js not supported. hardhat.config.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.                                             Instead rename hardhat.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).
```

If I change to `type: commonjs` I get this error if I run `npm run dev`:

```
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
svelte.config.js:1
import preprocess from "svelte-preprocess";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

If I change `svelte.config.js` to `svelte.config.mjs` I get the follwing error: `You need to create a svelte.config.js file` and if I rename `hardhat.config.js` hardhat doesn't find the config and wants to create a new project.

Is there any way to combine these two even tho there is a mixture of `import` and `require` statements?

Comment: Hello Paul, I'm trying the same, did you pass through this problem?

Comment: sadly not really, I worked around this issue by just splitting the project into two folder

Comment: Ok, thank you for your confirmation, I finally did the same :-)

Comment: Just ran into this as well. Kinda frustrating that we still don't have a consistent import system in 2022.